# React native navigation: Use a modal screen inside a drawer navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer, stack-navigator

I have been using a StackNavigator from [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org) and I have been able to use `presentation: 'modal'` to show a screen as a modal within the stack.

I've now found it would be best to use a drawer navigator for a set of nested screens within my app.

However, now the screen doesn't act like a modal at all. Is it possible to have a modal screen within a drawer navigator?

My Drawer navigator looks liks:

```js
const AccountDrawer = createDrawerNavigator()

function AccountScreen() {
    return (
        <AccountDrawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Overview">
            <AccountDrawer.Screen
                name="Overview"
                component={Account}
            />
            <AccountDrawer.Screen
                name="Login"
                component={LoginView}
                options={() => ({
                    title: 'Login or sign up',
                    presentation: 'modal',
                })}
            />
            <AccountDrawer.Screen
                name="About"
                component={About}
            />
        </AccountDrawer.Navigator>
    )
}

export default AccountScreen
```

Screenshot of what it looks like:
[image]

Screenshot of what I need it to look like:
[image]

Is this even possible with a drawer?

Comment: Any reason why you are not using https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal ?

Comment: Because I’d like to be able to navigate to and from the screen using the react-navigation functionality 